# Non-case sensitive query with TaffyDB (or other JS DB)

Tags: javascript, taffydb

I'm  using TaffyDB for a "DB" for the website I am working on right now. Its pretty neat, I can do 'like' searches. However, the 'like' search is still case sensitive and that if a record exist: "Banana", a query of "banana" will fail.

- Anyone knows how to use TaffyDB for such query
- Or, is there a JS DB that can do such function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `likenocase`:

`db( {title:{"likenocase":val}} ).order( ...`

Comment: Wow, it has been a month, and its just like that, cool! thanks!